# How to run windows game in full screen with wine?

Tags: wine, games, fullscreen

I have installed an Windows XP old time game with Wine, it works great, but I can't run it in full screen.

I have very basic Wine 2.18 setup. How do I run my game in full screen? So that also keyboard and mouse are force hijacked ([How to force wine to hijack keyboard and mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962615/how-to-force-wine-to-hijack-keyboard-and-mouse))

Comment: In my experience (I play these old games using Wine all the time) it's mostly a function of the in-game settings. Have you set the in-game settings to full screen and appropriate resolution? Turned off windowing in-game?

Comment: Hey, strangely this particular game doesn't have that setting in game! .. It's Project IGI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_I.G.I.:_I%27m_Going_In

Comment: Googling make it appear that this problem might have existed in windows as well - for instance https://dotsisteam.blogspot.com/2013/05/full-screen-intel-graphics-problem-in.html

Comment: **Do not post duplicate questions.**

Comment: This is about full screen, not keyboard and mouse. I need both, but it's a separate question.